# Hide proccess window (mstsc) C#

Tags: c#, process, user32

The issue I have is that I want to hide the process `mstsc` (Remote Desktop Connection). I tried using multiple methods such as `SW_HIDE` that works to some extent.

My goal -  launch a remote desktop connection and immediately hide it.

But the issue it only hides the first window (the connecting window), but if I add a button and wait for it to connect and then click it, it will hide the window. But I want this to work automatically. I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

```
private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
[DllImport("User32")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);


Process rdcProcess = new Process();
rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = 
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v " + "127.0.0.2"; // ip or name of computer to connect
rdcProcess.Start();

foreach (Process process in array)
{
    if (process.ProcessName == "mstsc")
    {
        int hWnd;
        hWnd = proccess.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
        ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to launch a remote desktop connection and immediately hide it? How does that make any sense? What's the big/long term *goal* here?

Comment: Yeah this what im trying to do. And its for my backconnect server. But yes. I want to immediately hide it.